# Fast Report converting a report to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, fastreport

Im trying to make a report to look good in HTML, as is having images and on those images text overlaping them, the problem is that when i convert a report to HTML in FastReport it moves all images to not overlap with any other object.

So the question is, is there any way to edit Css/JScrip inside a report to make images show as i want? like adding:

```
img
{
margin-right:-1px;
}
```

or

```
.test
{
margin-right:-1px;
}

<img class='test'>
```

but i cannot edit them manually i need fast report to do it, with functions, events or any possible way, if its posible.

Thank you.

This is what i get from Fast Report:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=Generator content="FastReport 4.0 http://fast-report.com">

<title>100</title>
<style type="text/css"><!-- 
.page_break {page-break-before: always;}
.s0 {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #000000; font-style: normal;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: Left; vertical-align: Top;
}
--></style>
</head>
<body
 bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">

<a name="PageN1"></a>
<table width="798" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr style="height: 1px"><td width="359"/><td width="2"/><td width="437"/></tr>
<tr style="height:161px">
<td class="s0" style="font-size:1px"><img src="http://i44.tinypic.com/29kqot1.jpg" width="805" height="571" alt=""></td>
</tr>

<tr style="height:251px">
<td  class="s1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body></html>
```

I want to put text above the image, but cant make it, i tried everything in Fast Report.
I tied to Divide The Images but the problem is that there is a 1px space between images in HTML, thats why i need Margin-right: -1px but cannot get it done,

Comment: Post some more code than just what you have and also consider putting an example of what you're trying to achieve in a `jsfiddle`

Comment: Added more info, i hope there is a way to acomplish what i want...

Comment: In my experience, writing the HTML export ourselves without FastReports produced more controllable results.  In fact, now we only use FastReports for PDF exports.

Comment: Yeah we had to rewrite some parts of the HTMLExport of FastReport, its just our clients use FR for reports and email, and suposdly they use a report to send it to people, thats why we had to adjust the Export for some styles, VML hacks etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We changed the source of the HTMLExport from the fast report, just in case some1 stumps with this problem.